# UML class diagram for MVC project that run R project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uml, r

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC project where controller calling static class that run R scripts from external R project

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Rscript.Run("WordCloud");// name of script file for example WordCloud
            return View();
        }
```

**Rscript**

```
 public static class Rscript
    {
        public static bool Run(string filename)
        {
            var rCodeFilePath = $"\\RProject\\{filename}.R";
            var rScriptExecutablePath = @"C:\Rscript.exe";

            var result = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var info = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = rScriptExecutablePath,
                    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(rScriptExecutablePath),
                    Arguments = rCodeFilePath,
                    RedirectStandardInput = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };


                using (var proc = new Process())
                {
                    proc.StartInfo = info;
                    proc.Start();
                    proc.Close();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //return false;
                throw new Exception("R Script failed: " + result, ex);

            }
        }
    }
```

1. How can I represent the relationship in UML class diagram between controller and static class Rscript?
2. Is there a relationship between R scripts files and MVC should represented in UML?

Comment: `Is there a relationship between R scripts files and MVC` -- The R scripts are part of the **Model.**

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you please explain why R scripts are part of models?

Comment: The short answer is "because they're not part of the View or the Controller."

Comment: @RobertHarvey so What are the features that make it a model?
I need a reason to support my answer please

Comment: It's not just any R script.  It's *your* R script.  It doesn't do anything to supplement the behavior of the Views or the Controllers, which means it's part of your Model by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I represent the relationship in UML class diagram between controller and static class Rscript?

I would need to see the complete controller class to be absolutely certain, but based on the code that you have demonstrated, the `Controller` and the class `Rscript` would each be represented by a class. There would be a Dependency between the `Controller` class and the `Rscript` class. Since `Rscript` is a static class and the controller doesn't hold onto an instance of one at a class level, it doesn't seem like you can use a stronger relationship, such as an Association. You can make sure to indicate that the Dependency is only one way, though - the controller is dependent on `Rscript`, but `Rscript` is not dependent on the controller.

To make the model more clear, you can use stereotypes on the `Rscript` class to indicate that it is static as well as to annotate the dependency.

> Is there a relationship between R scripts files and MVC should represented in UML?

Because the scripts live outside of your application and are separate entities, I would not expect them to show up on a class diagram.

Instead, you may want to show the interactions between systems on diagrams such as a component diagrams or activity diagrams. You can also use a sequence diagram to define the behavior of the `Rscript` class's `Run` method. If the script executables are sufficiently complex, you may have various sequence or data flow diagrams for those as well.

Comment: controller class only contains the above index actionresult